# Page Break Expressions in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm using the Power BI Report Builder.
Is there a way to insert a page break using an expression?
I need to be able to force a page break based on a value in a dataset field.
Is this possible?

All I'm finding is the ability to check a box to indicate a page break before or after a group.

Comment: Can you add a sample value and expected output from that?

Comment: No, You can not add page break based on value from dataset.  For that you need to add static value and based on that you can add page break on dataset.